# In the AlternationIndex trigger, why doesn't my background property work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-controls

code show as below：
This is part of my custom datagrid appearance.

```
        <Style x:Key="DatagridStyle_1" TargetType="DataGrid">
            <!--<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource Datagrid_HearderStyle_1}"/>
            <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource Datagrid_CellStyle_1}"/>-->
            <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ConTemplate_DgRow_1}"/>
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridTemplate1211}"/>-->
```

```
        <Style x:Key="ConTemplate_DgRow_1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" 
                                   >
                            </Border>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                                        ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                        />
                            
                        </Grid>
                        <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" Background="LightGreen" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"/>
                        </Border>-->
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00BCD4"/>
                            </Trigger>-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00BCD4"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>

                </Setter.Value>
                
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

this part doesn't work,but the other part
`<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen"/>` works fine

In the above code, I set the AlternationIndex trigger in the penultimate part of the code. In the same trigger, the Foreground property has already taken effect, but the Background property has never taken effect. I have modified the cell template and datagrid template before, and set their background color to transparent, but it has no effect.

I'd like to understand why this is the case and how to make setting the background color work.

Comment: The cells (DataGridCell) have their own background, which overlaps the background of the Row.
If you have free space in the DataGrid markup that is not allocated for columns, then in it you can see the effect of your trigger.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand "free space", some space of column is not in my datagrid, and the color doesn't change following the AlternationIndex trigger.In addition, why can the foreground attribute be changed with he AlternationIndex trigger?

Comment: You should use snoop to take a look at the various objects make up your ui. I think you will then see that there are controls which have their own background on top of the background you're setting.

Comment: Without the complete code that reproduces your problem, it is not possible to answer your question.
Template implementation details are needed, not only rows, but cells. A cell can take colors from a row, or it can have its own colors. It is also necessary to reproduce the DataGrid with the problem. Maybe the reason is not in the templates at all, but in how you use them.
Please create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, upload it to GitHub and provide a link.